# Ajax POST and php query

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Been looking at some tutorials, since I'm not quite sure how this works (which is the reason to why I'm here: my script is not working as it should). Anyway, what I'm trying to do is to `insert` data into my database using a PHP file called `shoutboxform.php` BUT since I plan to use it as some sort of a chat/shoutbox, I don't want it to reload the page when it submits the form.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(document).on('submit', 'form#shoutboxform', function () { 

            $.ajax({  
              type: 'POST',  
              url: 'shoutboxform.php',  
              data: form.serialize(),
              dataType:'html',  
              success: function(data) {alert('yes');},
              error: function(data) {

              alert('no');
              }
            });  
            return false;  

              });

        });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
require_once("core/global.php");
if(isset($_POST["subsbox"])) {
    $sboxmsg = $kunaiDB->real_escape_string($_POST["shtbox_msg"]);
    if(!empty($sboxmsg)) {
        $addmsg = $kunaiDB->query("INSERT INTO kunai_shoutbox (poster, message, date) VALUES('".$_SESSION['username']."', '".$sboxmsg."'. '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."')");
    }
}
```

And HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="shoutboxform" action="">
                <input type="text" class="as-input" style="width: 100%;margin-bottom:-10px;" id="shbox_field" name="shtbox_msg" placeholder="Insert a message here..." maxlength="155">
                <input type="submit" name="subsbox" id="shbox_button" value="Post">
            </form>
```

When I submit anything, it just reloads the page and nothing is added to the database.

Comment: Do some research on sql injection. Generally, it is a bad practice to build your query as you are doing. Use parameters.

Comment: It's because the jquery `on('submit'...` method is submitting your post, that has `action=""`, which means that the post form is sending to the current page (thats why you just see the page reloaded).

Comment: I don't see where `form` is initialized before you call `form.serialize()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prevent the default submit behavior

```
   $(document).on('submit', 'form#shoutboxform', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'shoutboxform.php',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data) {
          alert('yes');
      },
      error: function(data) {

          alert('no');
      }
  });
  return false;
});
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); doesn't seem to help, it's still reloading the page and nothing happens at all.

Comment: Nothing else than Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: I just updated the code. That is just a silly syntax error that was in my example.

Comment: Now it doesn't reload and it returns "yes". However it does not seem to run my php script. Not even if I put the script in action in the html form.

Comment: My advice from here is to check your browser dev tools network panel to review the request and response sent to/from your server.  In terms of getting your insert to work, there's a whole laundry list of stuff that could be wrong with that. Your database permissions have to be right, your database connection has to be right. Take your time and patiently study up, it's worth the time.

Comment: Actually, I fixed it by removing the if(isset(post)) in the php file! Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Use the following structure:

```
$('form#shoutboxform').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your ajax
}
```

Or https://api.jquery.com/submit/ :

```
$("form#shoutboxform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your ajax
});
```

Comment: I tried both methods, it still reloads the page and nothing happens.

Comment: Any javascript error in the console? And whats that `form.serialize()` exactly?

Comment: Sorry that was just an awkward typo that made it to not work!

Comment: Ok :) Next time first build the javascript and debug it. ...afterwards the php. You get a lot of more help here, if you are sharing an example with https://jsfiddle.net/ or something similar.